# Add Item To List Project Menu in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Good afternoon,

I would like to know how I can add a menu item in the list of Projects and how to get the id of a Project based on my selection made.
Below I attached a picture.

**Menu item in the list of projects:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SuiteCRM you can use this as an example. This will create an additional menu item in your Project ListView and get the Project id(s) as well.

**custom/modules/Project/views/view.list.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');

class ProjectViewList extends ViewList
{
    /**
     * @see ViewList::preDisplay()
     */
    public function preDisplay()
    {
        parent::preDisplay();

        $this->lv->actionsMenuExtraItems[] = $this->buildMyMenuItem();
    }

    /**
     * Builds the extra menu link(s)
     *
     * @return string HTML
     */
    protected function buildMyMenuItem()
    {
        global $app_strings;

        return <<<EOHTML
<a class="menuItem" style="width:150px;" href="#" onmouseover='hiliteItem(this,"yes");'
        onmouseout='unhiliteItem(this);'
        onclick="sugarListView.get_checks();
        if(sugarListView.get_checks_count() &lt; 1) {
            alert('{$app_strings['LBL_LISTVIEW_NO_SELECTED']}');
            return false;
        }
        document.MassUpdate.action.value='displaypassedids';
        document.MassUpdate.submit();">Menu Extra Item</a>
EOHTML;
    }
}
```

**custom/modules/Project/Controller.php**

```
<?php

class ProjectController extends SugarController
{
    public function action_displaypassedids()
    {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['uid'])) {
            $recordIds = explode(',', $_REQUEST['uid']);
            foreach ($recordIds as $recordId) {
                $bean = SugarModule::get($_REQUEST['module'])->loadBean();
                $bean->retrieve($recordId);
                echo "Sent Record ID {$bean->id}</br>";
            }
        }
        sugar_die('');
    }
}
```

Good luck.

[image: Extra Menu Item Example]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution solved my problem. It saved me a lot of time.